# onCreate() and onPause() called incorrectly from other activities

Tags: android, android-intent

My problem is that onCreate() and onPause() in a closed activity gets called when they shouldn't.

I the Start activity i call:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SelectTransportActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
this.finish();
```

when i want to start the SelectTransport activity.

But when i want to start the Stop Activity from the SelectTransport activity and i call

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, StopActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
this.finish();
```

I can see in the debugger that the onCreate() in the Start activity is called before the Stop activity starts.

Similarly, when I finishes the Stop activity, the onPause() in the Start activity is called, after which the Start activity starts.

Why are the onCreate() and onPause() called in the Start activity from the other activities when they shouldn't and I have finished the activity?

[image: Activities]

The manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.greenenergy"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <!-- Launching -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS" />
<!-- All probes -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<!-- Storage -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<!-- Location probe -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
    android:name=".GreenEnergyApplication">

    <service android:name="edu.mit.media.funf.FunfManager" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="default"
            android:value="@string/default_pipeline" />
    </service>

    <receiver
        android:name="edu.mit.media.funf.Launcher"
        android:enabled="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOCK_EVENT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SCREEN_ON" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.greenenergy.StartupActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.greenenergy.StartActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_start" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.greenenergy.WaysActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_ways" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.greenenergy.StopActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_stop">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.greenenergy.StatisticsActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_statistics">
    </activity>
</application>
```

The Start activity:

```
public class StartActivity extends BaseActivity implements OnClickListener {
private Button bStart, bStats;
Controller controller;
GPSCollectorSingleton gpsCollectorSingleton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    init();

    autoDetect();
}

private void init() {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    bStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bStart);
    bStats = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bStatisticsStart);

    bStart.setOnClickListener(this);
    bStats.setOnClickListener(this);

    controller = new Controller(); // Init controller
    Database database = new Database(getApplicationContext());
    controller.controlDatabase(database);
    controller.createTable(); // Create table if not exist

    gpsCollectorSingleton = GPSCollectorSingleton.getInstance(); // Init model

    // Bind to the service, to create the connection with FunfManager
    getApplicationContext().bindService(new Intent(this, FunfManager.class), funfManagerConn, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

private void autoDetect() {
    boolean auto = ((GreenEnergyApplication) getApplication()).getAutoPreference(getApplicationContext());
    boolean started = ((GreenEnergyApplication) getApplication()).getStartPreference(getApplicationContext());

    if (auto && !started) {
        controller.enableAutoDetection(getApplicationContext(), gpsCollectorSingleton);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    this.finish();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent;
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.bStart:
        startDataCollector();
        break;
    case R.id.bStatisticsStart:
        intent = new Intent(this, StatisticsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    }
}

private void startDataCollector() {
    if (((GreenEnergyApplication) getApplication()).getStartPreference(getApplicationContext()) == false) {
        controller.datahandlerObserver(getApplicationContext(), gpsCollectorSingleton); // Observer
        ((GreenEnergyApplication) getApplication()).setStartPreference(getApplicationContext(), true);
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, WaysActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

The SelectTransport activity:

```
public class SelectTransportActivity extends BaseActivity implements OnItemClickListener {

GridView gridview;
private static int DATABASE_ID_OFFSET = 2;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ways);

    gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() { 
    super.onPause();
    this.finish();
}



@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    ((GreenEnergyApplication)getApplication()).setTransportationPreference(getApplicationContext(), arg2+DATABASE_ID_OFFSET);
    Log.i("WayActivity",
            "ARG0: " + arg0.toString() + " Arg1: " + arg1.toString() + " "
                    + " Arg2: " + arg2 + " Arg3: " + arg3);
    Intent i = new Intent(this, StopActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
}
```

The Stop activity:

```
public class StopActivity extends StartActivity implements OnClickListener, Observer {

Button stopButton, statsButton;
TextView statusTextView;
int distance, time, transportTypeEstimate, transportType;
int sessionStartTime = 0;
int sessionStartDistance = 0;
GPSCollectorSingleton gpsCollectorSingleton;
LocationData location;
boolean transportEstimation;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    GPSCollectorSingleton gps = GPSCollectorSingleton.getInstance();

    if (((GreenEnergyApplication) getApplication()).getStartPreference(getApplicationContext()) == false) {
        Log.i("STOP - STOP", "hasspeed");
        stopDataCollector();
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_stop);

    stopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bStop);
    statsButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bStatisticsStop);
    statusTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvStatus);

    stopButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    statsButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    gpsCollectorSingleton = GPSCollectorSingleton.getInstance(); // Init model
    gpsCollectorSingleton.addObserver(this); // Observe on models state

    initTransportTypeDetection();
}

/**
 * Initializes estimating of transport type or manually chosen transport type
 */
private void initTransportTypeDetection() {
    transportType = ((GreenEnergyApplication) getApplication())
            .getTransportationPreference(getApplicationContext());
    transportTypeEstimate = transportType;

    if (transportType == TransportationDefinerSingleton.TRANSPORT_UNKNOWN) { // Start transport type estimation
        TransportationDefinerSingleton transport = TransportationDefinerSingleton.getInstance(); // Get model
        transport.addObservable(gpsCollectorSingleton); // Add observer for estimating transport type
        transportEstimation = true;
    } else { // Transport type manually specified
        setSessionStartDistanceAndTime();
        transportEstimation = false;
    }
}

private void setSessionStartDistanceAndTime() {
    Controller controller = new Controller();
    Database database = new Database(getApplicationContext());
    controller.controlDatabase(database);

    sessionStartDistance = controller.getDistanceFromID(transportType);
    sessionStartTime = controller.getTimeFromID(transportType);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent;
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.bStop:
        stopDataCollector();
        break;
    case R.id.bStatisticsStop:
        intent = new Intent(this, StatisticsActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, -1);
        break;
    }
}

private void stopDataCollector() {
    ((GreenEnergyApplication) getApplication()).setTransportationPreference(getApplicationContext(),
            TransportationDefinerSingleton.TRANSPORT_UNKNOWN);
    ((GreenEnergyApplication) getApplication()).setStartPreference(getApplicationContext(), false);

    gpsCollectorSingleton.deleteObservers(); // Delete all observers

    Controller controller = new Controller();
    Database database = new Database(getApplicationContext());
    controller.controlDatabase(database);
    // Get unknown data. From estimate of transport type or data collected while deciding transport type.
    int distance = controller.getDistanceFromID(TransportationDefinerSingleton.TRANSPORT_UNKNOWN);
    int time = controller.getTimeFromID(TransportationDefinerSingleton.TRANSPORT_UNKNOWN);

    if (transportEstimation) { // Estimate
        controller.updateTable(transportTypeEstimate, distance, time);
    } else { // Manually chosen transport type
        controller.updateTable(transportType, distance, time);
    }
    controller.resetTable(TransportationDefinerSingleton.TRANSPORT_UNKNOWN);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, StartActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    this.finish();
}

@Override
public void update(Observable observable, Object data) {
    Controller controller = new Controller();
    Database database = new Database(getApplicationContext());
    controller.controlDatabase(database);
    transportTypeEstimate = getTransportType();
    distance = controller.getDistanceFromID(transportType) - sessionStartDistance;
    time = controller.getTimeFromID(transportType) - sessionStartTime;
    location = (LocationData) data;

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String transportName = getTransportName(transportTypeEstimate);
            statusTextView.setText("Transport type: " + transportName + " Distance: " + distance + " Time: " + time
                    + "\nTimeStamp: " + location.getTime() + "\nSpeed: " + location.getSpeed()
                    + " Seconds since last: " + location.getSecondsSinceLastSample());
        }
    });
}

private int getTransportType() {
    if (transportEstimation) {
        TransportationDefinerSingleton transport = TransportationDefinerSingleton.getInstance();
        Controller controller = new Controller();
        controller.controlTransportationDefinerSingleton(transport);
        transportTypeEstimate = controller.getTransportType();
    }
    return transportTypeEstimate;
}

private String getTransportName(int type) {
    switch (type) {
    case TransportationDefinerSingleton.TRANSPORT_UNKNOWN:
        return "Unknown";
    case TransportationDefinerSingleton.TRANSPORT_WALK:
        return "Walking";
    case TransportationDefinerSingleton.TRANSPORT_BIKE:
        return "Bike";
    case TransportationDefinerSingleton.TRANSPORT_CAR:
        return "Car";
    case TransportationDefinerSingleton.TRANSPORT_BUS:
        return "Bus";
    case TransportationDefinerSingleton.TRANSPORT_TRAIN:
        return "Train";
    case TransportationDefinerSingleton.TRANSPORT_MOTORCYCLE:
        return "Motor Cycle";
    case TransportationDefinerSingleton.TRANSPORT_CARPOOL:
        return "Carpool";
    }
    return "";
}
```

}

The Base activity, which is the superclass for the other activities. It just sets up the option menu and other basic stuff.

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
private Controller controller;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GPSCollectorSingleton gpsCollectorSingleton = GPSCollectorSingleton.getInstance(); // Init model
    controller = new Controller();
    controller.controlGPSCollectorSingleton(gpsCollectorSingleton); // Init controller
}

protected ServiceConnection funfManagerConn = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        Log.i("OnServiceConnected", "MainActivity");
        controller.onServiceConnected(service);
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        controller.onServiceDisconnected();
    }
};

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_settings:
        disableService();
        closeActivity();
        return true;
    case R.id.action_clear:
        Database database = new Database(getApplicationContext());
        database.dropTable();
        return true;
    case R.id.action_toggle_auto:
        if (item.isChecked()) {
            item.setChecked(false);
            ((GreenEnergyApplication) getApplication()).setAutoPreference(getApplicationContext(), false);
        } else {
            item.setChecked(true);
            ((GreenEnergyApplication) getApplication()).setAutoPreference(getApplicationContext(), true);
        }
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    if (((GreenEnergyApplication) getApplication()).getAutoPreference(getApplicationContext()) == true) {
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_toggle_auto).setChecked(true);
    }
    return true;
}

/**
 * Disables the service and the pipeline
 */
private void disableService() {
    controller.disablePipeline(); // Disable pipeline
    boolean isBound = false;
    isBound = getApplicationContext().bindService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FunfManager.class),
            funfManagerConn, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    if (isBound) {
        getApplicationContext().unbindService(funfManagerConn); // Disable
                                                                // service
    }
}

private void closeActivity() {
    this.finish();
}
}
```

Comment: Paste the manifest declarations of these Activities too.

Comment: Paste the code for all `Activities` please.

Comment: What about `BaseActivity`.  What are you doing there in the life cycle callback methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with the easy things: Your `StopActivity` extends `StartActivity`

```
public class StopActivity extends StartActivity {...
```

It should either extend `BaseActivity` or a call to `super.onCreate()` will run the code in `StartActivity.onCreate()`.

Comment: Of course... I have no idea why I didn't see that. That solved the problem.